# Need advice for fiding crash probleam in qt c++ application

Tags: c++, qt

My Qt C++ application is crashed randomly. I generate its crash log and get below detail.

```
GNU gdb (Debian 7.12-6) 7.12.0.20161007-git
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./LaserModule_Debug...done.

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 10616]
[New LWP 10624]
[New LWP 10625]
[New LWP 10626]
[New LWP 10631]
Core was generated by `/home/user/AA/Application'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x76576ade in ?? ()
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 10616)]
(gdb)
```

I'm running **qt c++** application and compile it with debug symbol

```
CONFIG += c++14 debug link_pkgconfig
```

I got core file from the kernel and I run this core file with binary contain GDB symbol.

My binary contains GDB Symbol but I am not able to get any proper point from gdb log.

So I think there is any shared library used by my application and in that shared library have an actual problem.

**What is my next step in finding this crash?**

Comment: Your assumption(s) **are** incorrect. `System.out.println("Hello\r\n".length());` outputs `7`. Exactly like `printf("%lu\n", strlen("Hello\r\n"));`

Comment: Nit: That should be `%zu` @Elliott Frisch

Answer (score 6):

Try running the below code:

```
class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello\r\n".length());
  }
}
```

Too see your assumption about "Hello\r\n" being of length 5 is incorrect.